# How do you remove attributes of a dropped image during a drag and drop operation?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, contenteditable

```
var holder = document.getElementById('cms');

holder.ondragstart =function(e)
{
dragID =e.srcElement.id;
dregCl =e.srcElement.getAttribute('class');
if(dragID ==='cms_tools'){ cmsPanel =document.getElementById('cms_tools'); }
}

holder.ondragover = function(e)
{
if(dragID ==='cms_tools')
{
cmsPanel.style.top = (e.clientY-7) +'px';
cmsPanel.style.left = (e.clientX-250) +'px'; }}

holder.ondragend = function(e)
{
delete window.dragID; 
if(dregCl ==='imglib'){
e.target.removeAttribute('width'); 
e.target.removeAttribute('height');
e.target.removeAttribute('class'); } }


holder.ondrop = function (e) 
{ 

}
```

It seems like it should be simple. I have images in a panel that are sized down with width= and height= and need them removed when the image is dropped. The code you see now does this but applies it to the source image instead of the destination image. I cannot seem to find what should be a one word solution to address the image being dropped rather then the source image. Please keep answers constrained to standard javascript, no proprietary libraries or convoluted suggestions. Please do not close this thread simply because this project has requirements that do not include the aforementioned exceptions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.ondragstart =function(e)
{
Img_Src_Drop =e.target.getAttribute('src');
dragID =e.srcElement.id;
dregCl =e.srcElement.getAttribute('class');
if(dragID ==='cms_tools'){ cmsPanel =document.getElementById('cms_tools'); }}
holder.ondragover = function(e)
{
if(dragID ==='cms_tools')
{
cmsPanel.style.top = (e.clientY-7) +'px';
cmsPanel.style.left = (e.clientX-250) +'px'; }}
holder.ondragend = function(e)
{
delete window.dragID; 
if(dregCl ==='imglib'){ 
e.preventDefault; 
document.execCommand('InsertImage',null,Img_Src_Drop); }}
holder.ondrop = function (e) 
{ e.preventDefault; }
```

It was little more than one word but the fix was to simply preventDefault and insert a new image. Not what I was looking for but it works as desired. Hope this post helps anyone else in a similar bind.